# Flex-Ajax Bridge issue on Safari

Tags: ajax, actionscript-3, apache-flex

My flex project uses FA-Bridge, and apparently in Safari browser I cannot call any of my public AS functions that have arguments passed in. For example I can call this AS function from javascript:

```
var myButton = CreateNewButton();  
myButton.setLabel('Click here');
```

But if I try calling it in a single statement like this:

```
var myButton = CreateNewButton('Click here');
```

In the above call safari throws an error # 1063, (i.e. Argument count mismatch) in the safari javascript console, and points to line 561 in FaBridge.js. It thinks I didn't pass in the requied parameters.
Now the above issue exists only on Safari. Both of the above approaches work on IE, Firefox and Chrome browsers.
Note: I am NOT using swfObject for embedding my swf.

Comment: Are you using any other javascript lib with it

Comment: No. I am only using FaBridge.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably do better as a comment than an answer... but I haven't the popularity for it I guess....

I've had a similar issue with bridging calls through js. After a lot of experimenting, I found that the HTML doc type was the problem. Some browsers just won't let those calls through if it doesn't like the doc type, or you are missing one altogether.

I ended up having to just go down [the list](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/doctype.html) until I found one that worked well in all the browsers I was testing. If I remember correctly, it was this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Perhaps the problems are unrelated, but I figured it would be worth a shot.

Cheers!